# Dynamically assign values - python

Tags: python

looking to improve the efficiency of my code, as while my current method works, i feel it can be improved

currently this is my code :

```
if ouroraddrlen == (4,):
        ouropip = struct.unpack(">bbbb", payload[6:10]) # Need to change this to accept ipv6 as well 
        print "Our I.P : ", ouropip
        notheirip = struct.unpack(">b", payload[10])
        print "No. of their I.P's : ", notheirip    
        theiroripv = struct.unpack(">b", payload[11])   
        print "Their I.P version:: ", theiroripv
        theiroraddrlen = struct.unpack(">b", payload[12])
        print "Length of their Ip : ", theiroraddrlen
        theirfirstip = struct.unpack(">bbbb", payload[13:17])
        print "First Ip : ", theirfirstip
        theirsecondip = struct.unpack(">bbbb", payload[18:22])
        print "Second Ip : ", theirsecondip
```

the output is :

```
Time :  (1401734263,)
Our onion address : 
Ip version :  (4,)
Ip length :  (4,)
Our I.P :  ( )
No. of their I.P's :  (2,)
Their I.P version::  (4,)
Length of their Ip :  (4,)
First Ip :  ( )
Second Ip :  ( )
```

i have removed the real ip's but they are just ipv4 addresses

however what i am wondering, is if it is possible to include an if statement after this section of code :

```
notheirip = struct.unpack(">b", payload[10])
        print "No. of their I.P's : ", notheirip
```

where if the notheirip is greater than zero and depending on the length of :

```
        theiroraddrlen = struct.unpack(">b", payload[12])
        print "Length of their Ip : ", theiroraddrlen
```

which would be either 4 or 16 then it would set the payload values of the next section

for example if notheirip = (2,) and theiroraddrlen = (4,) then i would want it to print out

theirip = struct.unpack(">b       << the number of b required so either 4 or 16 and then the range, this will always start at 13 and go up to either 4 or 16 in the future and loop until all the ip's are displayed

not sure if that is clear but hopefully it is :)

Thanks

Comment: Might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52295/dynamically-assign-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Record = namedtuple("Record","IP NoIP IPV LenIP FirstIP SecondIP")
>>> Record._asdict(Record._make(struct.unpack(">LbbbLL",payload[6:])))
{'FirstIP': 1145324612, 'NoIP': 17, 'SecondIP': 1431655765, 'IP': 3140690449L,
IPV': 34, 'LenIP': 51}
>>>
```

I think would work (you might want different 4 byte type than L)  (keep in mind i totally made up the payload so I would expect different results with a real one)

if you want to get 4 digit tuples for the ips just unpack the new value

```
new_record["IP"] = stuct.unpack("bbbb",new_record["IP"])
```